# I want to calculate the mean of two rows in matlab

Tags: matlab, mean

I have a 1028 by 18 matrix in matlab.I want to calculate the mean of 1st and 2nd row by column values,3rd and 4th and so on in Matlab and get a new matrix with the mean values.

Answer (score 4):

I think you want to calculate the column-wise mean of every pair of rows. Reshape the array to be 2 x 18*1028/2, calculate the mean (which operates column-wise), and reshape the result to be 1028/2 x 18:

```
>> x = rand(1028, 18);
>> result = reshape(x, 2, 1028/2*18);
>> result = mean(result);
>> result = reshape(result, 1028/2, 18);
```

A quick test to demonstrate the speed of vectorized solution compared to a for-loop over pairs of rows:

```
>> x = rand(1028, 18);
>> tic; result1 = zeros(1028/2, 18); for ii = 1:1028/2; result1(ii,:) = mean(x((2*ii-1):(2*ii),:)); end; toc;
Elapsed time is 0.022432 seconds.
>> tic; result2 = reshape(x, 2, 1028/2*18); result2 = mean(result2); result2 = reshape(result2, 1028/2, 18); toc;
Elapsed time is 0.000388 seconds.
```

Comment: What do you mean by using 3rd and 4th column?I want to calculate the mean of 1st and 2nd row, 3rd and 4th and so on.Could I do this in a for loop.That would be more useful

Comment: @user1687051 - The vectorized solution above avoids a `for` loop which should be significantly faster.

Comment: This is not what i want.I am just getting two values with the above code.I want a whole new row with the mean values of first two rows

Comment: @user1687051 - You must be looking at the old answer. The current answer results in a 514 x 18 array.

Comment: Yes this is what I want.But is this more better than a for loop to calculate mean of every pair of rows.And I am assuming the above code calculates mean of 1st and 2nd row, 3rd and 4th row and so on.

Comment: @user1687051 - Yes, the vectorized solution will be significantly faster (see the results of one comparison in the answer above). See the Mathworks documentation on [vectorization](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/vectorization.html) for more info. This technique is definitely worth investing some time into learning if you're going to do more in MATLAB.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you are looking for is:

```
x = rand( 1028, 18 );
meanx = ( x(1:2:end,:) + x(2:2:end,:)) / 2;
```

After running this, `meanx` will be a [514 x 18] matrix.

The first row of `meanx` is the average of rows 1 and 2 in `x`.

The second  row of `meanx` is the average of rows 3 and 4 in `x`.

The third row of `meanx` is the average of rows 5 and 6 in `x`.

**EDIT**:

If you also want to exclude some of the rows from the averaging procedure based on the value of the first row, then you can add the following:

```
dx = diff(x(:,1));

goodrows = (dx(1:2:end) == 0);  %find row-pairs for which the first elements match
badrows = ~goodrows;

goodmeans = meanx(goodrows,:)  %average rows with matching first element
badmeans = meanx(badrows,:)    %average rows with non-matching first element
```

Comment: Could you help me if I want to compare the first elements of rows 1 and 2,(compare the first elements of the row and the row after it)and find the mean only if they are equal.

Comment: @Anand , I edited my answer to hopefully address your question. I recommend that if you are going to be using MATLAB further then you should invest some time learning these basics -- a few hours of practice with a good tutorial and you will have the hang of it.

Comment: Thank you for the advice and help.I will definitely invest more time to learn matlab

Answer (score 0):

Building on excellent answers by b3 and cjh. This one is the fastest

```
m=1028;
n=18;
D=rand(m, n);

% compute mean for two neighboring rows
D=reshape(D, 2, m/2*n);
D=(D(1,:)+D(2,:))/2;
D=reshape(D, m/2, n);
```

Measured in a for loop for 2000 iterations

```
b3         Elapsed time is 0.264215 seconds.
cjh        Elapsed time is 0.134812 seconds.
my version Elapsed time is 0.087994 seconds.
```

It is clear why. b3 uses function mean, which is not so good for performance if we just want to compute average of two numbers. On the other hand, clever reshapes make sure that we do not have to jump all over the memory during reading of the data, as is the case in the version of cjh. Hence, combining the best of the two solutions gives best results..

Comment: There is a slight change I am supposed to do the mean if the first two elements of 1st and 2nd row are equal.Example:1st row [1 2 3 4]  and 2nd row [1 5 6 8]. So do the mean as 1=1.I will have to write a for loop and if statement for this .Am I right or is there any other shorter way?

Comment: @angainorI am sorry for repeating myself but I am stuck at a point. I have a 1028 by 18 matrix with some entire rows having NaN values.So I need to compare the first two elements of adjacent rows and calculate the average only if the first two elements are equal. D is the 1028 by 18 matrix                                           [m,n]=size(D); for i=1:m-1 if D(i,1)==D(i+1,1) D=reshape(D, 2, m/2*n); D=(D(i,:)+D(i+1,:))/2; D=reshape(D, m/2, n); else end end