# I want to calculate the mean of two rows in matlab only if the first elemensts of thee two rows are equal

Tags: matlab, mean

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [I want to calculate the mean of two rows in matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12588152/i-want-to-calculate-the-mean-of-two-rows-in-matlab)

I am sorry for repeating myself but I am stuck at a point.
I have a 1028 by 18 matrix with some entire rows having NaN values.So I need to compare the first two elements of adjacent rows and calculate the average only if the first two elements are equal.
D is the 1028 by 18 matrix

```
 [m,n]=size(D);
    for i=1:m-1
    if D(i,1)==D(i+1,1)
    D=reshape(D, 2, m/2*n);
    D=(D(i,:)+D(i+1,:))/2;
    D=reshape(D, m/2, n);
     else
      end 
    end
```

Comment: What do you want to do with the result?  Put it in another matrix?  Where?  What do you want to put there if the first 2 elements *don't* match?  If you answer the questions and write it down in the form of code, you'll probably have your answer.  Or at least a question that's detailed enough for someone to answer.

Comment: It might also help to explicitly write out, a very small matrix, with some rows you average and some you don't, and then show what the result of your function would be.

Comment: Why not ask the same question again? Third times a charm. DON"T repeat yourself. Edit that first question instead.

Answer (score 1):

I do not have matlab with me but the logic will be something like this

```
for row=0,row++

    if ( m[row,1]  == m[row+1,1])
    {
        mean1 = mean(m[row]);
        mean2 = mean(m[row+1]);
        mean = mean(mean1,mean2);
    }

end for
```

/* note this syntax is not correct, it just give you the idea */

Comment: it gives you the idea, how to compare first element of the two adjacent rows and find the mean. Or do you want a full solution :)

Answer (score 1):

You can have  a logical index of the valid rows according to your definition using `all(~diff(D(:,1:2)), 2)`, i.e. the elements where both first and second column, row-wise difference is zero.

Then you can use this index to return either integer line indices or index within a matrix of global row-wise mean.

```
index_row = 1:1:size(D, 1); % linear row index 
index_valid = all(~diff(D(:,1:2)), 2); % valid rows (logical)

mean_matrix = (D(1:end-1,:) + D(2:end,:))/2; % matrix of all means

% matrix of valid mean rows only
mean_matrix_valid = mean_matrix(index_valid,:); % logical index 
% linear index of valid rows, i.e. the pairs indexed (i, i+1)
index_row_valid = index_row(index_valid); % valid rows (int)
```

For example with

```
D = [1 2 3 4 5; 1 1 1 1 1; 1 2 4 4 4; 1 2 3 3 3; 2 2 2 2 2; 2 2 3 3 3];

>> D = 
     1     2     3     4     5
     1     1     1     1     1
     1     2     4     4     4
     1     2     3     3     3
     2     2     2     2     2
     2     2     3     3     3
```

you will get, using the above

```
>> index_valid =

     0
     0
     1
     0
     1

>> index_row_valid =

 3     5

>> mean_matrix_valid =

    1.0000    2.0000    3.5000    3.5000    3.5000
    2.0000    2.0000    2.5000    2.5000    2.5000
```

which are the means of rows (3,4) and (5,6) respectively.